# Activator.CreateInstance with dynamic Type

Tags: c#

I think I have a lack of understand, what exactly is happening:
The user can enter a Path to an Assembly and an Object type and I try to create a instance of it.

My approach:

```
        Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFile(txtAssemblyPath.Text);
        Type myType = a.GetTypes().ToList().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == txtObjectName.Text);

        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance<myType>();
        var obj2 =(myType) Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
```

The problem is in the Creation of the Object itself. It seems like the myType is not threated as a Type. On this example: [Creating generic variables from a type - How? Or use Activator.CreateInstance() with properties { } instead of parameters ( )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708925/creating-generic-variables-from-a-type-how-or-use-activator-createinstance)

They just get an object, so I guess this is not the same Case. What I dont understand at all: CreateInstance(Type) works, but CreateInstance with the Type doesn't, but T and Type should be the same: System.Type.

Thanks in advance for clarifying.

Matthias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a using difference... When you write:

```
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance<myType>();
```

You used your Class like a Type, and it's the good way to do it.
You used a generic type who have a reference to a class type.

But there:

```
var obj2 =(myType) Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
```

You used you class like an instance (object). And you can't do that, a class is a schema.
If you want to call the second method, you have to write:

```
var obj2 =(myType) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(myType));
```

This code will create an instance of the class Type, and this instance will describe your class myType.

I hope to be clear.

A class is a schema, you can create an object with this schema, it will be an instance (a memory-object of your class).

Comment: Sorry, probably I'm just to stupid. According to MSDN about typeof:
"Used to obtain the System.Type object for a type. A typeof expression takes the following form:"

Type is generally just a Class aswell, if I go into it:
public abstract class Type : MemberInfo, _Type, IReflect

So wouldn't I always have an Instance, otherwise the Reference would be Null?

Comment: No you are not. ;)
Type is a class (schema), but like you said, typeof create an object (instance) of the class Type (schema).For your understanding, you could replace typeof by Activator.CreateInstance<Type>().

It's a bit complicated, because in this case your Type object will be a description of your class (schema).

Comment: I think I see it: A Type can be a Instance of Type Type(wtf?) or a Scheme. Do you know how this Scheme is marked or saved? But my question is answered so far.

Comment: There are some syntaxic norm... The First letter of a word is to reference a Class (schema). When said schema, it was for describe the "utility" of a Class, if you prefer, it's like a Blueprint. But yes, you can have an object (instance) of class Type who describe the class Type.

Answer (score 3):

When you use generic type of method such as `Activator.CreateInstance<T>();` you have to provide **Strong Type** of T. That means you have to pass known type name instead of T. for example:

```
var activatorPerson = (Person)Activator.CreateInstance<Person>();
```

That's why there is a **non generic form** of `Activator.CreateInstance(typeGoesHere)` function which can be used in cases that we do not have a **Strong Type** at moment of creation of an object. So we can pass type as a parameter to that function. we can provide type variable in lots of ways. In your case you find the proper type in your assembly as following:

```
Type myType = a.GetTypes().ToList().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == txtObjectName.Text);
```

also you have to notice that explicit casting as you typed in your code is not valid:

```
obj2 =(myType) Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
```

because you have to provide **Strong Type** name for explicit casting.
when we do not have access to strong type names at run time, we have to use non generic versions of methods.

Comment: Sorry, I used "Strong type" for something else: You mean with "Strong type" a type, which is known at compile time? And there is no way to make a explicit casting possible?
And: Is there a Indicator, when a strong type is needed and when not? Genereally they're both System.Type?

Comment: Strong Type is a "name of type" not variable of that type. For example string is Strong Type but when we code string name = "Matthias" name.GetType() is a type of string in a variable form. Yes strong types are known at compile time to the compiler. As i said the only way to do explicit casting is by providing strong type name and not a variable of that type.

Comment: All generic versions of methods and types such as List<T> must be provided by strong types. In cases that you do not have strong type you have to provide type as instance of that type [typeof()] can be used in such cases. Or you can use reflection in scenario like your one.

Comment: Do you have a example? From what I know typeof only works with Compile-Types:
typeof takes a type name (which you specify at compile time).

Comment: I meant typeof(Strong Type) would give an instance of that Strong Type to use it in cases that you need instance of type instead of Strong Type. So did you get your answer? If my answer was useful mark it please.

Comment: Yeh, sorry, so there is no Indication when to use strong types and when to use instances? This is more for interesting purposes.

Comment: All generic implementations (for classes, structs, methods , etc) must be used with Strong Types. Such as List<T> or Activator.CreateInstance<T>(). But in cases that accept parameter as type instance we are free to get type by any possible way in scenario.

Comment: There is a combination of these two approaches and it's a possibility to use Reflection. You can handle some cases in which you do not have strong type, but you should use it. For example suppose that I need List of T, I can use reflection to create that: typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(typeGoesHere)

Comment: In your case you can call generic type of CreateInstance like this :  var genericMethod = typeof (Activator).GetMethods().Where(info => info.Name == "CreateInstance" && info.IsGenericMethod)
                .SingleOrDefault();
            var result = genericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeGoesHere).Invoke(null,null);

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pure dynamic way.

This is the factory class and dynamic instance create method:

```
    public class RepositoryFactory
{
    public static dynamic CreateDynamic<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        dynamic repositoryInstance = null;
        var subRepositories = AssemblyHelper.GetSubclassesOf(typeof(BaseRepository<TEntity>), true);
        var entityTypeName = typeof(TEntity).Name;
        var subRepository = subRepositories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == entityTypeName + "Repository");
        if (subRepository != null)
        {
            var repositoryType = subRepository.UnderlyingSystemType;
            repositoryInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(repositoryType);
        }
        return repositoryInstance;
    }
}
```

This is the helper class for mapping types between Entity and Repository.

```
public static class AssemblyHelper
{
        public static List<Type> GetSubclassesOf(Type type, bool ignoreSystem)
        {
            List<Type> lReturn = new List<Type>();
            foreach (var a in System.Threading.Thread.GetDomain().GetAssemblies())
            {
                if (ignoreSystem && a.FullName.StartsWith("System."))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                foreach (var t in a.GetTypes())
                {
                    if (t.IsSubclassOf(type) || (type.IsInterface && t.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(e => e.FullName == type.FullName) != null))
                    {
                        lReturn.Add(t);
                    }
                }
            }
            return lReturn;
        }
}
```

This is the Manager class for use case:

```
public class PageManager
{
    private readonly ContentPageRepository _pageRepository;
    public PageManager()
    {
        _pageRepository = RepositoryFactory.CreateDynamic<ContentPage>();
    }

    public void GetPagesByContentType(ContentType type)
    {
        var pages = _pageRepository.GetByPredicate(x => x.Status != EntityStatus.Deleted && x.Node.Type == type);
        foreach (var page in pages)
        {
            //Deal with it :)
        }

    }
}
```