# Instantiating a new object of T inside of a generic function in C#

Tags: c#, object, generics, generic-programming

I have two models that can both use the function below. I created an Interface that both of these models implement.

In the function below I am looping through the passed in list and using the values in it to create a new version of the list.

```
public static IList<T> GenericFunction<T>(IList<T> objList) where T : IProduct
{
    // In this function I am doing the following:

    IList<T> retVal = new List<T>();

    foreach (T obj in objList)
    {
        T newObj = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

        newObj.Price = obj.BasePrice + obj.OldPrice;
        newObj.Description = obj.Name + " " + obj.Description;

        retVal.add(newObj);
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

**The above code is working, but I have a couple of questions:**

In order to have a function like the above that works with any model that implements IProduct, doing what I did is my only option right? At first I was thinking I could just simply create a standard function that takes `IList<IProduct>` as a param and returns `IList<IProduct>`. But then I ran into the problem of instantiating a new object which led me to creating a Generic Function.

Additionally, can I use an object initializer on newObj to set its properties?

After seeing this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708925/creating-generic-variables-from-a-type-how-or-use-activator-createinstance) I feel like I should be doing something different.

Comment: Really? You can create an instance of an interface? `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(obj))` makes more sense to me...

Comment: Isn't he making an instance of a type that derives from the interface?

Comment: Why don't you add the  `new` constraint and write `T newObj=new T();` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that `IProduct` will always have a paramterless constructor, you can achieve this through generic constraints:

```
public static IList<T> GenericFunction<T>(IList<T> objList) where T : IProduct, new()
{
    IList<T> retVal = new List<T>();

    foreach (T obj in objList)
    {
        T newObj = new T();
        newObj.Price = obj.BasePrice + obj.OldPrice;
        newObj.Description = obj.Name + " " + obj.Description;
        retVal.Add(newObj);
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

`new()` constrains T such that it must have a parameterless constructor - allowing it to be instantiated via `T newObj = new T();`.

Comment: Hmm I am getting the following intellisense error on: T newObj = new T(); cannot create an instance of the variable type T because it does not have the new() constraint.

Comment: Did you add the `where T : IProduct, new()` bit?

Comment: I missed that! Now it works. What exactly is adding new() telling it? So as long as it has a constructorless param I can do this right?

Comment: It is telling the compiler that the type `T` must have a constructor that takes no arguments, so it knows it is able to create it using `new T()`.